# MarketingCloudSDK | In App Messaging | Button URLs not handled in delegate

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk

I migrated the MarketingCloudSDK from **Version 7.5.1** to **Version 8.0.0**.

[image: Package Dependencies in my Project]

For some reason the buttons of the In App Messages are not handled anymore. The problem is that the delegate `sfmc_handle(_ url: URL, type: String)` is not getting called.

I set the url handling delegate `SFMCSdk.mp.setURLHandlingDelegate(self)`after the SDK was successfully configured.

```
let completionHandler: (OperationResult) -> Void  = { result in
  if result == .success {
    SFMCSdk.mp.setURLHandlingDelegate(self)
  } 
}
```

Also I confirm to the `URLHandlingDelegate` protocol.

```
extension SalesforceConfigurator: URLHandlingDelegate {
    func sfmc_handle(_ url: URL, type: String) {
        print("Debug: sfmc_handle url")
    }
}
```

This worked before with the SDK **Version 7.5.1**. However, with the SDK **Version 8.0.0** the delegate is not getting called if I click any of the buttons.

In the journey builder my setup looks like this.

[image: In App Message Setup on the journey Builder]

Is there something else I need to configure or change?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known bug already which will be fixed in the next update. Please log a support ticket if you wish to be notified when the update is released.

Comment: Thanks you for the information. Can you please tell me where I can log a support ticket? And is there maybe any reference support ticket I can refere to in my own support ticket?

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002mLEcQAM&title=mobilepush-sdk-ios-v8-0-3-opendirect-url-does-not-trigger-the-call-back-in-delegate

Comment: Thank you EazyE!